# nightly build update introduces compilation error

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I know that nightly builds on Rust are "unstable" so there's no guarantee they continue to work with each update but I had a major issue with the rollout of rust 1.68.

The following code compiles for rust 1.67 but forms a cycle in 1.68.

The issue, specifically, is calling `T::do_something.to_bytes` which requires putting a `where` clause in the `do_something` function header. Adding `[(); T::MyType::NLEN]:,` to the where clause causes the breakage but also is required for generic constants. Any insight as to why this is happening which could help me learn more about Rust is much appreciated.

**CODE:**

```
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

// FUNCTION THAT IS NOW BROKEN
fn do_something<T: SuperTrait>() where [(); T::MyType::LEN]:, [(); T::SUPER_SIZE]:  {
    let _ = T::do_something_super().to_bytes();
}

// Trait I implement for a few subtypes of my main type "SuperTrait"
trait MySerde {
    const LEN: usize;

    fn to_bytes(&self) -> [u8; Self::LEN];
    fn from_bytes(bytes: [u8; Self::LEN]) -> Self;
}

// each subtrait would have its own requirements
trait SubTrait: MySerde {
    // stuff
}

// We need a subtrait for constants or we get a cycle when defining SUPER_ARR
trait ConstantsForSuper {
    const SUPER_SIZE: usize;
}

// in my actual example SuperTrait has several types implementing differeent subtraits
// (all of which require serde)
trait SuperTrait: ConstantsForSuper where [(); Self::SUPER_SIZE]: {
    type MyType: SubTrait;

    const SUPER_ARR: [Self::MyType; Self::SUPER_SIZE];

    fn do_something_super() -> Self::MyType;
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when building an abstract representation for `do_something::{constant#0}`
 --> src/main.rs:8:45
  |
8 | fn do_something<T: SuperTrait>() where [(); T::MyType::LEN]:, [(); T::SUPER_SIZE]:  {
  |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: ...which requires building THIR for `do_something::{constant#0}`...
 --> src/main.rs:8:45
  |
8 | fn do_something<T: SuperTrait>() where [(); T::MyType::LEN]:, [(); T::SUPER_SIZE]:  {
  |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...which requires type-checking `do_something::{constant#0}`...
 --> src/main.rs:8:45
  |
8 | fn do_something<T: SuperTrait>() where [(); T::MyType::LEN]:, [(); T::SUPER_SIZE]:  {
  |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: ...which again requires building an abstract representation for `do_something::{constant#0}`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when checking that `do_something` is well-formed
 --> src/main.rs:8:1
  |
8 | fn do_something<T: SuperTrait>() where [(); T::MyType::LEN]:, [(); T::SUPER_SIZE]:  {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0391`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad title, stackoverflow didn't like my first few attempts. I would also appreciate anyone sending me in the correct direction to report this error to the Rust community/issues list.

Comment: Fill an issue at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/new?assignees=&labels=C-bug%2C+regression-untriaged&template=regression.md.

Comment: An issue may [already be filed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/106420) but I'd create a new issue since I can't tell if they're caused by the same core problem or not.

Comment: Issue [filed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/107265)